# laravel form, data not storing into the database

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, migrate

this is my blade file

@csrf

name

@if ($errors->has('name'))
{{ $errors->first('name') }}
@endif

```
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required autofocus>
                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <span class="Enter properly">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Mobile-no</label>
                        <input type="text" name="mobile-no" class="form-control" id="mobile_no" placeholder="Enter your mobile no" required>
                        @if ($errors->has('mobile-no'))
                            <span class="Enter 10digits">{{ $errors->first('mobile_no') }}</span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="Enter properly">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label>Confirm-password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Re-enter your password" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6" align="center">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" style="width:80px;">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </form>
@endsection
```

This is my controller file

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\FormController;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Hash;
    use Session;
    use App\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades;
    
    class FormController extends Controller
    {
    
        public function index()
        {
            return view ('login');
        }
    
        public function postLogin(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'email' => 'required',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);
        
            $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
            if (User::attempt($credentials)) {
                return redirect()->intended('dashboard')
                            ->withSuccess('Signed in');
            }
       
            return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Login details are not valid');
        }
    
        public function registration()
        {
            return view('registration');
        }
        public function postRegistration(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required',
                'mobile_no' => 'required',
                'password' => 'required|min:6',
                'confirm_password' => 'required', 
            ]);
    
            $data = $request->all();
            $check = $this->create($data);
              
            return redirect("dashboard")->withSuccess('have signed-in');
    
         }
    
         public function create(array $data)
         {
           return User::create([
             'name' => $data['name'],
             'email' => $data['email'],
             'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
           ]);
         }    
    
         public function dashboard()
        {
            if(User::check()){
                return view('dashboard');
            }
       
            return redirect("login")->withSuccess('are not allowed to access');
    
        }
        public function signOut()
        {
            Session::flush();
            User::logout();
       
            return Redirect('login');
        }
    
    }
```

//this is my route file

```
Route::get('dashboard', [FormController::class, 'dashboard']);
Route::get('login', [FormController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('post-login', [FormController::class, 'postLogin'])->name('login.post');
Route::get('registration', [FormController::class, 'registration'])->name('register');
Route::post('post-registration', [FormController::class, 'postRegistration'])->name('register.post');
```

//this  is my migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customRegistration', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->integer('mobile_no');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('confirm_password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('form');
    }
}
```

i created simple laravel login & registration form.laravel is not genrating errors. but it is not stored a data into the database i.e any of data will be not stored in database.